# How to run CMD script instead of building and starting C++ console application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmd

I created a Win32 C++ console application. I want to run some CMD scripts instead of building and running this app. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what commands do you want to run?

Depending on the complexity of your logic, it's ok to scrap your Win32 C++ console application and just use "Batch files".  (That's assuming you are running on a Windows operating system that is Windows 7 or earlier versions).

Batch files have a myriad of operations and operators that you can use to execute commands and even has some logic structures and ability to pass in parameters and call other batch files as if they were sub procedures.

You'd do best buying a book on Batch files.

Also you can google:
"Batch files",
"DOS Files", and
"Win32 Shell Scripting" to get tutorials on all the in's and out's of writing a batch file.

You can use any text editor to write a batch file (like note pad, etc).  In order to make it a batch file, you name the file with a `.bat` extension.

By running the batch file in a command prompt window, the computer will execute the commands in the file as if you were typing them into the prompt yourself.

The one drawback is that Batch files are much slower than other compiled languages.  But if speed and memory size is not an issue, then there is nothing wrong with using them.

Give us more details if you want more of an explanation.

Best of luck :)